# What is the meaning of 从中 in 有人却从中感受到对自由?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

抽象派画家的作品中经常见到好像随便洒上颜料而形成的画作，在有人看来极其神秘甚至丑陋，有人却从中感受到对自由、对生命的赞美。

This is from the Standard Course Book of HSK5, chapter 18.

What is the meaning of 从中?

According to dictionaries, 从中 is an adverb meaning "from".

I am here:

有人(some people)却(however)从中(from)感受到(feel)对(towards)自由(freedom)、对(towards)生命(life)的赞美(admiration / eulogization)

As you can see, I cannot make it have sense...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What is the meaning of 从中?

My understanding is that "中" is like "it", "that", and "which" in English. "从中" means "from it" (from something that is mentioned in the context).

For example, 读完 莫言 的 小说，我 从中 学到 很多 的 东西。(After reading MoYan's novel, I learned a lot from it. ）

有人(some people)却(however)从中(from)感受到(feel)对(towards)自由(freedom)、对(towards)生命(life)的赞美(admiration/eulogization)

However, some other people are able to feel the admiration of the artists for freedom and life from their art.

Answer (score 1):

从中 is a compound word that includes the meaning of each individual word to form a new meaning.

- 从(from)中(among/within)

Comment: The original and complete form of 从中 is 从什么什么中 (from something, among something). For example, 有人却从（这些艺术作品）中感受到对自由、对生命的赞美。

Comment: IMO, "From it" = 从它, 它 is the 作品, a "作品" is for visualization/reading. "From within" = 从中, 中 represents the 作品中的涵義, which is something for understanding and learning. Though the difference between the two is quite small.